# python - simple elevator simulator...works perfecty then abruptly stops. why?

Tags: python

I am brand new at programming. I am making a simple elevator simulator. I have the basic structure that works just fine but after the user inputs their selection 3 or maybe 4 times the command line just closes. Is there something wrong with my code? Or is there something about the commandline that automatically closes after a certain amount of time?

```
floor_select = int(raw_input("Please select floor 1-10:  "))
current_floor = 1

while floor_select > current_floor:
    current_floor += 1
    print "You are currently on floor:  " + str(current_floor)

    if floor_select == current_floor:
        print "You have arrived at floor " + str(current_floor)
        floor_select = int(raw_input("Please select floor 1-10:  "))

while floor_select < current_floor:
    current_floor -= 1
    print "You are currently on floor:  " + str(current_floor)

    if floor_select == current_floor:
        print "You have arrived at floor " + str(current_floor)
        floor_select = int(raw_input("Please select floor 1-10:  "))
```

Comment: You're stuck on a loop that only runs until a condition is true. `current_floor` keeps going down 1 until the condition is exhausted.

Comment: @tobias_k And what exception would be raised?

Comment: @Zizouz212 None, you are right. The program just ends after so and so many user inputs.

Comment: Or rather when the loop has run so many times it's condition is simply exhausted.

Comment: As shown, this code would terminate, quietly and without exception, after the following input: 4, 3, 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit one of your `while` loops the first iteration around, and then after you reach your condition and have another user input for `floor_select`, you are *still* within that `while` loop. As a result, if for instance you are in the second while loop and your new input requires the first while loop, your program will simply end, as your `while` loop will terminate.

You cannot expect to re-enter the first or second `while` loop after the inequality condition is no longer met. A workaround would be to place your code in an actual function, and call your function once again after you reach your desired floor in the elevator simulator.

Comment: I was really expecting Donkey Kong to suggest you just use ladders and ramps instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you are not looping over your entire construct.  So, once you have gone up and gone down your program exits.

I agree with Donkey Kong who said you need to use function definition(s).  I personally would structure it something like:

```
def goup(target_floor, current_floor):
    # insert contents of first while loop here
    return current_floor

def godown(target_floor, current_floor):
    # insert contents of second while here
    return current_floor

if __name__ =='__main__':
    # your set up code (first two lines)
    while floor_select != -1:
        if floor_select < current_floor:
            current_floor = godown(floor_select, current_floor)
        elif floor_select > current_floor :
            current_floor = goup(floor_select, current_floor)
        else:   # must be ==
            print ("Already there!")
        # get user input
        floor_select = int(raw_input("Please select floor 1-10:  "))
```

and remove the getting the user input from the while loops in the functions.

Edit : added current_floor as function parameter.

Comment: This won't work because of scope shenanigans; make the functions take a current_floor as well.